# Check is service running within laravel

Tags: php, laravel

If I am using Laravel Scheduler and Laravel Echo Server.

```
$schedule->exec('laravel-echo-server start')
         ->everyMinute()
         ->onSuccess(function () {
             // send logs
         })
         ->onFailure(function () {
             // send failure message and retry
         });
```

Is there a way to check is laravel-echo-server active or down?
I saw that I could use supervisor to auto-restart services etc.
Is there a way to do it within laravel without supervisor or any other similar program?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, you might wanna check if the port occupied. It's a solid way of checking such services. Something like `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` would give you the list of used ports, then you can simply check for the port.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Trying to make a process manager in Laravel?

Comment: @OzanKurt now thats the solid answer, I will try that. I also saw `fsockopen`, that may work good as well.

Comment: Then, I should send it as an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna check if the port occupied. It's a solid way of checking such services.

Something like `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` would give you the list of used ports, then you can simply check for the port.